# Getting consecutive number for each partition in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table (**sample** data):

```
CREATE TABLE A
    ([Idx] int, [Title] varchar(50), [Sort] int)
;    
INSERT INTO A
    ([Idx], [Title], [Sort])
VALUES    
    (6, 'b', 1),
    (6, 'b', 2),    
    (6, 'b', 3),

    (4, 'a', 4),
    (4, 'a', 5),    
    (4, 'a', 6),

    (7, 'c', 7),
    (7, 'c', 8),    
    (7, 'c', 9)
;
```

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
ORDER BY Sort
```

Result:

```
| Idx | Title | Sort |
|-----|-------|------|
|   6 |     b |    1 |
|   6 |     b |    2 |
|   6 |     b |    3 |
|   4 |     a |    4 |
|   4 |     a |    5 |
|   4 |     a |    6 |
|   7 |     c |    7 |
|   7 |     c |    8 |
|   7 |     c |    9 |
```

I would like to get consecutive number starting from 1 for each partition in the query. (the partition is by `Idx`)

Expected result:

```
| Idx | Title | Sort | N |
|-----|-------|------|---|
|   6 |     b |    1 | 1 |
|   6 |     b |    2 | 1 |
|   6 |     b |    3 | 1 |

|   4 |     a |    4 | 2 |
|   4 |     a |    5 | 2 |
|   4 |     a |    6 | 2 |

|   7 |     c |    7 | 3 |
|   7 |     c |    8 | 3 |
|   7 |     c |    9 | 3 |
```

preferably using `? OVER (PARTITION BY Idx ORDER BY Sort)` if possible.
I must also maintain the `Sort` order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you did not want to use DENSE_RANK() you could do something like the following:

```
select A.*, B.GRP from A
INNER JOIN (
select row_number() over(order by srt) GRP,idx
FROM ( select  idx,MIN(sort) srt from A group by idx) t1 ) B
on A.Idx = B.idx
order by sort
```

Comment: I can't use DENSE_RANK() b/c it gives the wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use of `DENSE_RANK()` function

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Title) N FROM <table_name>
```

Result :

```
Idx Title Sort  N
6   a     1     1
6   a     2     1
6   a     3     1
4   b     4     2
4   b     5     2
4   b     6     2
7   c     7     3
7   c     8     3
7   c     9     3
```

Comment: that was the first thing I tested. `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Idx ORDER BY Sort) AS rnk` does not work.

Comment: @zig have u checked that above query or just remove `(PARTITION BY Idx)` ?

Comment: I must also maintain the `Sort` order. sorry for not making this clear in my question which I edited.

Comment: I can not sort by `Title`. I need to sort by `Sort`. as I said in my q it is a sample data.  I have changed the data a bit, so that you can understand the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(
select *, row_number()over ( order by idx ) as rwnum,DENSE_RANK() over (Order  by title) as rank 
 from #a 

)

,cte3
as
(
select c.Idx as idx1,c.Title as title1,c.sort as sort1,c.rwnum,c.rank ,a.Idx ,a.Sort,a.Title
from
cte as c 
join #A as a on c.rwnum=a.sort
)

select idx,Title,Sort,rank from cte3
```